# Can someone explain why this code works-making div stick to top after scoll?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I love that this code works, but I cannot, for anything, wrap my head around WHY it's working?

Here is the [jfidddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uFq2k/)

Here is the code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    clone = $('div').clone();
    $('div').after(clone);
    $('div:last').hide();

offset = $('div:first').offset();
var fromtop = offset.top;

$(document).scroll(function() {
    doc = $(this);
    dist = $(this).scrollTop();

    if (dist >= fromtop) {
        $('div:last').show();
        $('div:first').css({
            'position': 'fixed'
        });
    } else {
        $('div:first').css({
            'position': 'static'
        });
        $('div:last').hide();
    }
});

});
```

I guess I am not understanding how scrolltop and offset are interacting or what they REALLY are, as in their true positions on the page. The code says if ScrollTop (the scrollbar position?) is higher than the value of the div's offsettop , then make the div sticky. But if ScrollTop is the position of the scrollbar, isn't it true that sometimes the scroll bar position could be lower than the div's position BEFORE the div is at the top of the page? What is it about being at the top of the page (offsettop of 0?)--and only at the top of the page, never before-- that makes offsettop a smaller value than scrolltop?

Really confused, and I don't want to just copy the code without understanding what it's really doing.

Comment: You've got a variable `stickyHeaderTop` that is the distance of your header from the top of your page. When the distance you scrolled down is greater than this variable, the header becomes fixed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's actually very simple. Let me try if I can make it a bit clear to you:

Whenever you want something (let's say some div) to get fixed on top as you scroll down, you need two things:

1. You need the current vertical position of your div. And you calculate that by using offset().top
2. You need to track how much user has scrolled. And you calculate that by using scrollTop()

So in your case, if the current position of your div is top: 100, then as soon as your scrollbar reaches the number 101, your div will get the class of .fixed

By default, the scrollbar vertical position is 0 when the page loads.

Answer (score 4):

scroll Top is actually how many pixels 'up' the page has moved (or how many pixels you have moved down the page)

Basically all that happens is the `.offset` sees how far down the page (from the top of the page)  the 'sticky' menu is

When you scroll to that point the bar becomes fixed (which is basically relative to the window instead of the document)

When you scroll back up it just switches back to being positioned in the document.

For clarity

```
.offset = 200px say - this is how far down the document the sticky menu is

.scrollTop - is 0 when the page loads
```

When you scroll down the page 201px

```
 .scrollTop > .offSet -> so make the bar fixed (remember fixed is relative to the window - not the document)
```

If you scroll back up the process is reversed.

Comment: Oh great! Thanks!! Very clear now. For some reason, all the textbook definitions were confusing me.

Comment: Glad could help - I always find if I cannot work something out console.log() on every item on a page is useful - you could then had quickly noticed what each variable does!